# Struts - redirect a jsp to another jsp by hiding parameters in the URL

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I have a struts application , where jsp1 has to redirect to another jsp on different server.While doing this I also want to send the parameters to other application and hide them [not showing them in the URL]

1) I first thought of writing a scriplet and do a response.sendRedirect(destination URL).By doing this, I could still see the  attached  parametersin the QueryString.

What are the possible options and if somebody could direct me in right way that would be gr8.

I am trying to do sth like this in my jsp

bean:parameter id="param1" name="param1" property="userName" />

<%

```
java.util.HashMap params = new java.util.HashMap();
params.put("userName", "param1");
params.put("passWord","param2");
pageContext.setAttribute("paramsName", params);
```

%>

homepage.jsp

Here is my struts config

```
<action path="/homePagePre"
        type="com.ford.mpl.superg.action.home.HomePagePreAction"
        name="homeForm" scope="session" validate="false" parameter="method" input="/jsp/APSTest.jsp">
        <forward name="httpGet" path="tile.home"></forward>
        <forward name="home" path="tile.home"></forward>
        <forward name="showBulletin" path="/jsp/home/completeBulletinMessage.jsp"></forward>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect, you have to pass the parameters in the URL. An HTTP redirect is simply a Location response header, so there's nowhere else to put data.

And, as you say, if the new location is in a different application (much less a different server), you can't "forward" to it.

Comment: is there a way to hide the parameters and do a redirect to another URL(application)

Comment: That's what I'm saying, no there isn't. Redirects *must* show the parameters.

Comment: I was trying to think through alternative approaches, but there may be none. The only other one I could think of would be for your application to act as an HTTP client and request the other server's page then forward that data back to the browser. That's unlikely to work, though, unless you can get that other server's application to change to actually process your request and return you a redirect of its own.

Comment: Please refer to the link below to see what I have done     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874985/javascript-onsubmit-to-struts-action-class-error